# Passing javascript variable to php via POST

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

I am trying to pass content of a div via POST first putting it into javascript variable:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x=document.getElementById("lambda");
  var promenna = x.innerHTML;

function nastavit()
{document.getElementById("formular").jsvalue.value = promenna;}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="lambda">
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
<form action="ulozit.php" method="post" id="formular">
<input type="hidden" name="jsvalue" value="javascript:promenna.toString()" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="nastavit();" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it works only when I set a specific value to the variable 'promenna', for example var promenna = "blah blah". What is wrong here?

Comment: Are there any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: I think you must wait for the page to finish loading or else the `document.getElementById('lambda');` won't return a valid element. You can use the body elements onload function for this.

Comment: Justin: Ah, thank you. Putting the script after the div helped.